# Python, concatenate each line of a file with one string

Tags: python, file, cpu-word, concatenation

```
palavra = raw_input('palavra: ')    
arquivo = open('palavras.txt', 'r+')
lendo = arquivo.readline()
print palavra + lendo
arquivo.close()
```

I want to concatenate each line of the "palavras.txt" with the value of the variable "palavra" but in the code above it's only concatenating with one line and the rest is read but isn't concatenated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't iterate through the other lines

```
with open('palavras.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for lendo in f:
        print palavra + lendo,
```

Comment: Why `for lendo in f.readlines():`? `for lendo in f:` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

read the whole of the file first

```
for line in arquivo.readlines():
    palavra = palavra+line

print palavra
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('palavras.txt') as palavrasFile:
  print palavras.join(palavrasFile)
```

Use

```
  print palavras + palavras.join(palavrasFile)
```

if you want the prepend the value of `palavras` also to the first line.  Spec isn't too clear on this.